# How to get daily count with date generate 2 - 2 days after in last 7 dates in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am create one query for the get daily last 7 dates email count in the sql server. and i am write one query but not given expected output the table. right now just give the count in last 7 dates. here below write my query and tell me where is my mistake.

This is my query =>

```
SELECT dateadd(day, T.i, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount 
        FROM (VALUES (-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
           SELECT Count(InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
           FROM Email
           WHERE Datediff(day,InsertDateTime, dateadd(day, T.i, getdate())) = 0 
        ) uf

This is my o/p=>
    DateColumn | Count
    15-06-2017    10
    16-06-2017    05
    17-06-2017    20
    18-06-2017    10
    19-06-2017    30
    20-06-2017    50
    21-06-2017    40


This is my Expected output =>

DateColumn | Count
03-06-2017    10
06-06-2017    05
09-06-2017    20
12-06-2017    10
15-06-2017    30
18-06-2017    50
21-06-2017    40
```

any one know how can do that please tell me.

Comment: Just a small tweak `dateadd(day, T.i * 3, getdate())` but i think your Count value will be changed.

Comment: in the table 03-06-2017 10 count and 06-06-2017 05 count so count will be same get or change?

Comment: @TriV still same o/p is come any other wave for that?

Comment: it will be different because your where clause returns more rows

Comment: You want the same o/p, then just change the select column value :)

Comment: @TriV i want to my Expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same Count value output then change it.

```
SELECT dateadd(day, T.i * 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount 
        FROM (VALUES (-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
           SELECT Count(InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
           FROM Email
           WHERE Datediff(day,InsertDateTime, dateadd(day, T.i * 3, getdate())) = 0 
        ) uf
```

Comment: with you solution date is come but my count is wrong come so how can fix it

Comment: The `apply clause` is the same so  your count value doesn't change. Then I change select column, i think it will work. Have you tried it?

Comment: where in apply clause can you please edit your solution please

Comment: with your solution in the table on date 18-06-2017 50 count is available but here getting 0 count

Comment: here WHERE Datediff(day,InsertDateTime, dateadd(day, T.i * 3, getdate())) = 0  write then count it's true come in the query thanks triv for the helping

Comment: triv please edit your solution then after will give the mark true

Comment: see in the my table on date 21-06-2017 store 40 count and 18-06-2017 50 count so with your solution it's come true then after i have add also in where clause with add t.i * 3  then its come true

Comment: can you please help me